# Can we ask any kind of wiki question here?

Tags: discussion, scope, public-beta

I have created [my own Area 51 proposal especially dedicated to wikis](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wiki-edit), but looking at this site it looks obsolete. Can we ask *any* wiki question here?

If so I can close mine down and redirect traffic here.

Can anyone think of a wiki related question that could not be asked here (excluding the questions excluded on FAQ)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In precedent, I haven't seen any “social” questions here yet (i.e., “How to deal with a potentially constructive vandal on my wiki?”), and I don't think they will be welcomed here.

So, don't close WikiSpeedia just yet =)

Comment: This might be on-topic in [communitybuilding.se] (beta)