# Should "Wikis and Wikipedia" be merged into Web Applications?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've asked a similar question [before](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546) and I'm also asking this on [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2703). But I'd like a response from people here.

Should [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716) be merged into Web Applications?

**Update:** we don't seem to have a consensus yet, but two of the three responses so far imply not all topics for *Wikis and Wikipedia* would be welcome here. Ideally, I'd like to see all questions on one site (hence the proposal). But if that's not possible, I guess we have to live with multiple questions on multiple sites. Any final comments? Otherwise I will accept one of the responses implying a "partially merge".

Comment: `Is Wikipedia a reliable source for doing research?` seems to be an acceptable question there, but would not here, I guess.

Comment: That proposal was deleted a long time ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have my doubts.

While

> navigating and editing Wikipedia, sharing of help and guidelines,

would certainly be on-topic here,

> managing and installing wikis,

would not.

These are borderline:

> administrating your Wikia / organization's wiki, MediaWiki, DokuWiki or others, writing wiki articles and its syntax,

And this is a useless catch-all:

> or any other wiki-related questions

I think about half of the proposed topics would be fine here, the rest not so much. So, then, where would the rest go, and, is it worth it to split them up?

Comment: The same split occurs with Facebook - using it is on topic, developing apps for it isn't, so it's not like there's not a precedent. However, I understand your concerns.

Comment: Would administration of a wiki fit better in Webmasters Stack Exchange?

Comment: @tepples It would seem so to me, but you should ask them.

Answer (score 7):

I think this might be a good idea.

Certainly Wikipedia qualifies as on topic, and I can't see a reason why other Wiki's shouldn't either.

If there's no response from people like [Robert Cartaino](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/10/) or [Rebecca Chernoff](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/416/) soon I'll try and get hold of them via chat.