# Would MediaWiki sites like Wiktionary be considered web apps for the purposes of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask some questions about Wiktionary, the dictionary sister site of Wikipedia, running on MediaWiki. But only if it's considered on-topic here since they're not very Web 2.0 compared to say Gmail.

If it is OK I would like to ask about Wiktionarys other than the English one - would that be on topic?

Answer (score 6):

As long as you are asking about **using** the sites, then yes you are on topic.

Using as a reader is definitely on topic.

Using as a contributor should be OK as you are still just using the software, albeit to create content. It's the same as, say, questions about uploading content to Facebook.

Using as an administrator is more problematical as this starts to get into areas of system setup and installation which are definitely off topic. However, some areas (setting up of user accounts perhaps) might be OK. I think we'd have to take these on a case by case basis.

See [this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/918/21) on the merging of the [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716) proposal.

Comment: Yes it would be about using them. But just to be clear it would be about using them as a contributor rather than just as a passive reader if that would make a difference.

Comment: @hippietrail - see update

Comment: I've [asked my question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18438/does-the-german-wiktionary-have-a-way-to-request-words-to-be-added) - let me know if it's "too localized". I would ask the German wiktionarians directly but I don't know how to go about that either.

Comment: Would questions about editing Wikipedia and MediaWiki be considered on-topic as well?